# How create a sub-forms in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

I will like to create 2 windows forms using vb.net

The 1st window forms is main and the second window forms is for sub-window forms and they appear at the same time when run the program

When i close the sub-windows forms it will not close my program, if i close the main window forms it will close my program.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Once you close your child forms to you need to reopen them

Answer (score 2):

When you open the second form, set the owner to the parent form and when you close the parent, it will force the child to close as well.  I believe (at least it seems it did this at one time in VB history) that if you hide the parent, it will hide the child too.

If you are using `SHOW` to display you 'Sub-Form', pass the parent form to it like this:

```
Form2.show(Form1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to close the owner form when the child form is closed and (if the owner is the starting form of the entire program) end the program, then you will first want to do what Steve has answered to assign form1 as the owner of form2.

Then, to make the child form close the parent, use the following code in form2's `FormClosed` event:

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    Me.Owner.Dispose()
End Sub
```